# how do I compare values from List using simple Odata filter?

Tags: sql, linq, odata

How do I write a filter which will compare Mylist-values to MyKeyTable-values?

I tried something like the following:

```
List<string> Mylist = new List<string>();
Mylist.Add("Welcome");
Mylist.Add("Hello");

var output = await client.For<MyKeyTable>()  
                         //this is wrong I knew I need to correct this        
                         .Filter(Mylist.Contains(x=>x.Key))
                         .FindEntriesAsync();
```

So `output` will come with all the values whoes Key-value matches as `welcome` and `hello`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done I tried it using custom expression

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTableClass), "entity");
            Expression expression = null;
            Expression predicateBody = null;
            Expression leftExpression = Expression.Property(pe, "Key");
            Expression rightExpression = Expression.Constant("Welcome");
            expression = Expression.Equal(leftExpression, rightExpression);

            predicateBody = predicateBody == null
                 ? expression
                 : Expression.OrElse(predicateBody, expression);
```